# Windows phone 7 live gps track

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, gps, windows-phone

I'm looking for some help about gps in windows phone 7. Actually I want to create an application to send GPS coordinates to my server in background every x seconds, is that possible?

Actually I read in some topics that it's impossible to get location in background in wp7, but my employer required me to find a solution...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to try to get the [location service in silverlight for Windows phone](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jprosise/using-the-location-service-in-silverlight-for-windows-phone) and try to implant it in [Windows Phone 7 Background Agent](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CSWP7ScheduledTaskAgent-6450bcf1)